# SQL Server linked server in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a linked ODBC server (not SQL Server) defined in my SQL Server Management Studio.

The only way I can query it is by using the `OPENQUERY` command, and that's fine - but it doesn't allow visual query editing or any intellisense.

Is there a way of typing queries against linked servers that behave in the normal way, even an extension?

Comment: Intellisense in SSMS is at best flaky on a good day, linked server or not. And visual query editing IMHO should be avoided as the various designers in SSMS are (or used to be) buggy and will often produce suboptimal queries.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and I wouldn't have thought of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try format like this:

```
<server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>
```

example:

```
select foo.id 
    from databaseserver1.db1.dbo.table1 foo
        inner join databaseserver2.db1.dbo.table1 bar 
            on foo.name = bar.name
```

Comment: PLease mark my post as answer if it fits oyur needs:) Thanks

Comment: This works perfectly, it doesn't really give me the intellisence I need but it's been advised that this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You use 3-dot syntax, like this,

```
<server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>
```

but it works properly only with linked servers to other instances of MSSQL.